# Class not found exception from OpenSSLSocketImpl after upgrading Security Provider

Tags: java, android, openssl, google-play-services

Per Android Developer and [Updating Your Security Provider to Protect Against SSL Exploits](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-gms-provider.html), the security provider in Android 4.x OS should be upgraded to avoid known vulnerabilities. Using the `ProviderInstaller` class of Google Play services, we can upgrade the same.

When we try to access the `OpenSSLSocketImpl` class as shown in below code snippet, it throws the class not found exception.

```java
Class.forName("com.google.android.gms.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl");
```

Why is `OpenSSLSocketImpl` causing a class not found exception?

What else should we perform to use the latest OpenSSL library?

Comment: @jww Thanks for improving the question.

Comment: Hi @jww, may be it is because play service is obfuscated ?

Answer (score 3):

The implementation classes are not part of the API, so you shouldn't reference them directly.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Agreed that OpenSSLSocketImpl is an internal class. But as shown in following link, OkHttp has provided model TLS features like SNI by using the reflection on OpenSSlSocketImpl of conscrypt and JSSE providers. Similarly, in case of Google GMS library, the same implementation is required to have the latest TLS extensions. But as said in question, it throws the exception while we do reflection. https://gitlab.com/tongyang/okhttp/blob/875cf4649412efcf231074f0ad745f8fa08bde1f/okhttp/src/main/java/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/Platform.java

Comment: Try using com.android.org.conscrypt package.

Comment: Yes that is working. And org.apache.harmony.xnet.provider.jsse.OpenSSLSocketImpl is also working in older Android OS. But due to having the vulnerability in older OpenSSL, Google has provided patch in GMS Conscrypt. The patch is installed in device. I checked the "GMSCore_OpenSSL" provider is there. But as said in above comment, the concerns here is to enable SNI, but cant as the reflection is not successful.

Comment: @user4756956 - *"the concerns here is to enable SNI, but can't as the reflection is not successful. ..."* - maybe the next path to take is ways to enable SNI without relying on reflection? The SNI functions `SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_servername_callback` (server) and `SSL_set_tlsext_host_name` (client) have been around since at least 1.0.1.

Comment: @jww thanks. But these are the internal functions of openssl library. Dont know how to use in Android.

Comment: Unfortunately, SNI is not part of the SSLSocket API. You can however get SNI support via HttpsURLConnection, see https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl.html. As for the GMSCore_OpenSSL provider, IIRC, it is doing some classloading tricks in order to make it possible to replace the SSL implementation on the fly. you might want to read the source for details

Comment: @Nikola Elenkov, Agreed we use HttpsUrlConnection and which has the default hostname verifier. Actually I'm not able to find on google the source of SSL implementation replacement, can you pls provide a link.

Comment: @NikolayElenkov, could you please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50735558/keys-lost-from-bks-file-without-deletekey-command ?